# Checking if an adress is linecache aligned

Tags: caching, alignment

This is a quiz question which I failed in the past and despite having access to the solution, I don't understand the different step to come to the correct answer.

Here is the problem :

Which of these adress is line cache aligned

```
a. 0x7ffc32a21164
b. 0x560c40e05350
c. 0x560c40e052c0
d. 0x560c3f2d71ff
```

And the solution to the problem:

```
Each hex char is represented by 4 bits

It takes 6 bits to represent 64 adress, since ln(64)/ln(2) = 6

0x0 0000
0x4 0100
0x8 1000
0xc 1100
________
2^3 2^2 2^1 2^0
8   4   2   1

Conclusion: if the adress ends if either 00, 40, 80 or c0, then it is aligned on 64 bytes.

The answer is c.
```

I really don't see how we go from 6 bits representation to this answer. Can anyone adds something to the solution given to make it clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question boils down to: Which number is a multiple of 64? All that remains is understanding the number system they're using.

In binary, 64 is written as 1000000. In hexadecimal, it's written as 0x40. So multiples of 64 will end in 0x00 (0 * 64), 0x40 (1 * 64), 0x80 (2 * 64), or 0xC0 (3 * 64). (The cycle then repeats.) Answer c is the one with the right ending.

An analogy in decimal would be: Which number is a multiple of 5? 0 * 5 is 0 and 1 * 5 is 5, after which the cycle repeats. So we just need to look at the last digit. If it's a 0 or a 5, we know the number is a multiple of 5.

Comment: This is the conclusion I came to, I just didn't understood the step taken by the solution.